# Known issues for VS2010 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2010

While I can find plenty of places that known issues are documented for beta releases and release candidates for Visual Studio 2010, I can't find anything for the release itself, and maybe it's just me but I don't see an easy way of querying connect to get a list of reported issues?

Is there a list of known issues for VS2010 RTM version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in Section 2 of the the Visual Studio 2010 Readme - get the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=133421

Comment: ah that explains a lot, our IT, in their (lack of) wisdom, appear to have blocked this link.